# How to pass 2 columns from a WEBGRID to an AJAX call

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have a WEBGRID that contains 2 columns.

I then make a row clickable by using Jquery and Ajax. I can pass in 1 value, which is the first column in the webgrid to the AJAX call, and this works fine. But i am unable to pass in 2 values to the AJAX call.

How can i do this ?

WEGRID CODE in a VIEW() .cshtml:

```
        @grid.GetHtml(columns: grid.Columns(
                        grid.Column("projectCode", "Project Code", canSort: true),
                        grid.Column("spUserName", "Provider Name", canSort: true)),
        tableStyle: "webgrid",
        headerStyle: "webgrid-header",
        footerStyle: "webgrid-footer",
        selectedRowStyle: "webgrid-selected-row",
        rowStyle: "webgrid-row-style")
```

JavaScript/AJax Call in the same VIEW() .cshtml:

```
            <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
            $('tbody tr').live('hover', function () {
                $(this).toggleClass('clickable');
            }).live('click', function () {  
                $.ajax(
                            {
                                type: "POST",
                                url: "/Projects/OtherProjectHeaderSP",                              
                                data : { projectCode: $(this).find('td:first').text(),
                                         spUserName: $(this).find('td:second').text()},
                                success: function (data) {
                                        $('#container1').html (data);                         
                                    }
                            });
            });
        });
        </script>
```

The problem is that it doesnt pick up spUserName: $(this).find('td:second).text()},
which is rthe spUserName. If i only pass in the $(this).find('td:first').text(), it works 100% with the projectCode being sent through to the controller. But by adding the second one, it causes a failure.

How can i pass in 2 values from the WEBGRID?

The other option is to use JSON. But i have tried and unable to assign the td values to a JSON object.

Any help please

Answer (score 0):

`td:first` is another way of saying `td:eq(0)`. Using that if you change it from `td:second` to `td:eq(1)` you can get the second column